# Could not find actionbarsherlock.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, android-logcat, android-build

I'm trying to run my app on a real device from Eclipse. After adding actionbarsherlock as a reference, I can't get rid of this error: `Could not find actionbarsherlock.apk`. Here is the full console output:

```
[2013-05-24 16:10:14 - MyApp] ------------------------------
[2013-05-24 16:10:14 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2013-05-24 16:10:14 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-24 16:10:14 - MyApp] Performing com.myapp.activities.StopSelection activity launch
[2013-05-24 16:11:26 - MyApp] Uploading MyApp.apk onto device '0A3AA80D1402500E'
[2013-05-24 16:11:26 - MyApp] Installing MyApp.apk...
[2013-05-24 16:11:33 - MyApp] Success!
[2013-05-24 16:11:34 - actionbarsherlock] Could not find actionbarsherlock.apk!
[2013-05-24 16:11:34 - MyApp] Starting activity com.myApp.activities.StopSelection on device 0A3AA80D1402500E
[2013-05-24 16:11:35 - Tahanot] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.tahanot/.activities.StopSelection }
```

The activity doesn't really start, and there's an error in LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myApp/com.myApp.activities.StopSelection}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myApp.activities.StopSelection in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myApp-2.apk]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myApp.activities.StopSelection in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myApp-2.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
    ... 11 more
```

None of the answers here helps: [android launch from eclipse not working properly without error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805449/android-launch-from-eclipse-not-working-properly-without-error-message)

Comment: Have you declared your StopSelection Activity in your Manifest?

Comment: If activities are not declared in the manifest it throws a ActivityNotFoundException as compared to the ClassNotFoundException. This is definitely a build error. Check my answer below to provide proper build settings to your app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can happen if you are not exporting **Build Path ->  Android Private Libraries** from your library project. This is something new that you have to do from ADTv22 and up.

Also from your console output, i see that the app is trying to upload an apk for the library. This can happen if you have not added the library in android properly. So here are a few quick steps:

1. Make sure your ABS lib project is marked as a Library. **Properties -> Android -> Check "Is Library"**
2. Make sure that for the ABS lib project, Android Private Libraries is checked in **Build Path -> Order and Export**. This step is only required for ADTv22 and up.
3. In your project add the ABS lib project as a library at **Properties -> Android -> Add Library**. Do not add the ABS lib project as a project dependency in the Build Path yourself, ADT resolves those as it requires, otherwise it generally throws an error like you see above.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your valid points, but unfortunately that's not it. Everything you mentioned looks ok.

Comment: Turns out I still had actionbarsherlock in Java Build Path -> Projects. I removed it, then added using Android -> Library -> Add, and the error message in the console stopped! I still have a ClassNotFoundException, but this is probably unrelated.

Comment: thats true. it had persisted a little bit for me. i also removed it from Properties->Java Build Path->Projects(tab) and made sure "Android Private Libraries" was checked under "Order and Export" in the same location

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you have add the Library project not correct into your android application project..

You have to the Sherlock library to your Project as below:

**Properties -> Android** in library section you can now add the Sherlock library

hope this helps..

Comment: I removed it and added it again, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Turns out I didn't remove it altogether, so I double-checked and it turned out I still had actionbarsherlock in Java Build Path -> Projects (see my comment on Samarath's answer).

Comment: Thank you.. I coupled your advise with the advise from Samarth Jain.. I was not importing Sherlock Library correctly!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove actionbar sherlock project folder from **`Properties`→`Java Build Path`→`Projects`** (tab) of your host project and
2. make sure **`Android Private Libraries`** was checked under **`Order and Export`** in the same location of my own project which uses action bar sherlock as library project - and it works.